# HTML: Link with relative target leads to unexpected address

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

On this site: http://www.nice2cu.de/testzugang/ at the bottom there are links like Impressum, Kontakt etc. that have a relative path in their href field:

```
<a href="impressum/">Impressum</a>
```

We are in the subfolder testzugang/ so I would expect the link to lead to http://www.nice2cu.de/testzugang/impressum. In reality, my browser opens http://www.nice2cu.de/impressum, without the subfolder. In fact the adress  http://www.nice2cu.de/testzugang/impressum returns a 404 error so it is not a bug in the browser, it is meant to lead to that adress. How come? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only likely explanation for this is that you have something like `<base href="http://www.nice2cu.de/">` changing the path from which relative URLs are calculated.

Comment: That is absolutely it! Thanks a lot, I didn't know that element.